# Add a dynamic menu to a site?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

***I want to add a dynamic menu to the frontoffice of my site where can i easely add a child menu or a new panel menu from the page admin . 
how can i do that using symfony***

Comment: See: https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle

Comment: how can i use it . I don't undestand it??

Comment: Did you look at the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

You should code that menu, it's a good training if you're new to symfony.

For a dynamic menu, I usually do :

- a Menu entity
- a MenuItem entity
- a controller for each, with a CRUD.
- an action in the MenuController do show the menu (as a HTML unordered list for example).

Then you can edit the ::base.html.twig in app/Resources/view and you add a block menu and render the MenuController :

```
{% block menu %}
  {{ render(controller('AcmeBlogBundle:Menu:list')) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

With knpmenubundle you can easily create a Menu with child.

First of all, look at https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle and read http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/KnpMenuBundle/index.html

Secondly use Doctrine and make a relation OneToMany (or ManyToMany but it's not recommended).

Use KnpMenuBundle as Service

Good luck !

Comment: Could you please add the important content from the links into your answer and use the links as reference only?